# mod_rewrite redirect of subdomain with subfolder combination

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code in my .htaccess to handle subdomains (http://foo.mydomain.com)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ filter.php?type=country&country=%1 [L]
```

The problem is what do i have to do if for example someone puts a link like this:

http://foo.mydomain.com/bar

i want to redirect this to another page different from the filter.php (say otherpage.php) from the previous code, i tried the next code but it isn't working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).mydomain.com/([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ otherpage.php?type=country&country=%1 [L]
```

neither the next one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ otherpage.php?pname=$1 [L]
```

The link is always resolved with the first rule i wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a condition to your first group that checks for an empty `REQUEST_FILENAME`.  This will prevent it from matching when there's something other than a bare domain name.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ filter.php?type=country&country=%1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks that take care of the requests for **subdomain.mydomain.com** but what to do with the links like **subdomain.mydomain.com/param** ??

Comment: **EDIT** actually, Weird thing is if i NEGATE the ^/?$ like this *!^/?$* then it works